# gmail api send email using content in html

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api

I am using the gmail api to send emails. The following is my code

```
function sendEmail(auth, from, to, subject, content) {

 var encodedEmail = new Buffer(
   'From: ' + from + '\r\n' +
   'To: ' + to + '\r\n' +
   'Subject: ' + subject + '\r\n\r\n' +

   content 
 ).toString('base64').replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

 var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
 var request = gmail.users.messages.send({
   auth: auth,
   userId: 'me',
   resource: {
     raw: encodedEmail
   }
 });
};
```

But the content in this case should be plain/text. The problem is that I want to pass the 'content' in HTML format. Any suggestion on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to provide a `content type` in your message, or it will default to `plain/text` as you mentioned. Just add a `Content-Type`-header with the value `text/html`:

```
From: sender@gmail.com
To: receiver@gmail.com
Subject: Foo bar
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<b> This is the content of the email </b>
```

Comment: Tholle... Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
Is encoding the content, but I noticed that the subject is not being encoded.
If the subject has a word like 'português' it shows 'portuguÃªs' 
Do you know how do I tell the gmail api to encode the subject to UTF-8 ?

Comment: [This blog post](http://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/) explains it. `var encodedSubject = '=?utf-8?B?' + btoa(subject) + '?=';`